# How to generate different types of component

Tags: components, vhdl

I have 3 different types of component. For example type0, type1 and type2. They all have the same ports but functions. I want to use a constant like 0, 1 and 3 to put the corresponding component in my top design.  I want to know the way to do this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `generate` statement, eg:

```
G0 : if SOME_CONSTANT = 0 generate
  I0 : type0 ( ...
end generate;
G1 : if SOME_CONSTANT = 1 generate
  I1 : type1 ( ...
end generate;
G2 : if SOME_CONSTANT = 2 generate
  I2 : type2 ( ...
end generate;
-- etc
```

If you use VHDL-2008, there is a `case`-`generate` statement:

```
G : case SOME_CONSTANT generate
  when 0 =>
    I0 : type0 ( ...
  when 1 =>
    I1 : type1 ( ...
  when 2 => 2 
    I2 : type2 ( ...
  -- etc
end generate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several architectures for the same entity :

```
entity my_component is
--(only one port declaration for all component)
end entity;

architecture type1 of my_component is
--(type1 behavior)
end architecture;

architecture type2 of my_component is
--(type2 behavior)
end architecture;

architecture type3 of my_component is
--(type3 behavior)
end architecture;
```

Then you can call whatever architecture you need in your top_level file :

```
typ1_inst0 : entity work.my_component(type1)
--(port map ...)

typ2_inst0 : entity work.my_component(type2)
--(port map ...)

typ3_inst0 : entity work.my_component(type3)
--(port map ...)
```